# How configure .NET Core Cors from localhost origin

Tags: c#, ionic-framework, .net-core

I've one Ionic-Angular frontend that consume a .NET Core REST api.

The Ionic-Angular APP runs in http:\localhost:8100

The .NET Core works fine with swagger, postman, and https://apirequest.io

But is not working with (from) http:\localhost:8100

The code is fine, enabling CORS as it should be:

Services:

```cs
services.AddCors(opciones =>
{
    opciones.AddDefaultPolicy(builder =>
   {
       builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:8100", "https://apirequest.io", "https://localhost:8100")
       .AllowAnyMethod()
       .AllowAnyHeader();

   });
});
```

and Configure:

```cs
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseCors();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers();
});
```

I don't understand why form "https://apirequest.io" works fine, and from "http://localhost:8100" does not?

The error shows by browser is:

> 'Solicitud de origen cruzado bloqueada: La misma política de origen no permite la lectura de recursos remotos en https://localhost:5001/api/socios. (Razón: Solicitud CORS sin éxito).'

Info about headers:

> ```
> GET   https://localhost:5001/api/socios
> Transferido0 B (tamaño 0 B)
> Política de referenciastrict-origin-when-cross-origin
>   
> Accept    application/json, text/plain, */*
> Accept-Encoding   gzip, deflate, br
> Accept-Language   es-ES,es;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
> Connection    keep-alive
> Host localhost:5001
> Origin    http://localhost:8100
> Referer   http://localhost:8100/
> Sec-Fetch-Dest    empty
> Sec-Fetch-Mode    cors
> Sec-Fetch-Site    cross-site
> User-Agent    Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:91.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/91.0
> ```

I think the error is produced by other configuration that I don't know it, because it's works from "https://apirequest.io". maybe because it's not from https?

I'm trying to configure https for Ionic but not succeded!

Comment: what if you remove the `https` entry for localhost?

Comment: Thanks, but there is a automatic redirect to https.

Answer (score 0):

I answer myself.

In chrome can allow localhost site even without https certificate:

chrome://flags/#allow-insecure-localhost

This solves my situation.

from: https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/154601-chrome-allow-localhost-site-even-without-https-certificate